# How to fix expected dense_11 to have 4 dimensions error

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I got some error when I was building a convolutional neural network with Keras:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_11 to have 4 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (48986, 12)

Since I lack knowledge, I have no idea what to fix. Can someone explain the reason and also suggest the solution?

```py
input_shape = (99, 81, 1)
nclass = 12

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Convolution2D(8,3,3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(nclass, activation='softmax'))

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=2017)
#vgg
batch_size = 128
nb_epoch = 1

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.fit(x_train,y_train,nb_epoch= nb_epoch,batch_size = batch_size , validation_split=0.1)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid), epochs=3, shuffle=True, verbose=2)
model.save(os.path.join(model_path, 'vgg16.model'))
```

`x_train` has a shape of (99, 81, 1) and the `nclass` output should be `12`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error again:
"Error when checking ***target***: expected dense_11 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (48986, 12)" - target=labels/output
Meaning, there is some kind of problem with your output shape.

Lets print the model summary to check what is the expected output shape:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 99, 81, 32)        64        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 97, 79, 8)         2312      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 48, 39, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 48, 39, 128)       1152      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 48, 39, 128)       16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 48, 39, 12)        1548      
=================================================================
Total params: 21,588
Trainable params: 21,588
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The final layer outputs predictions with shape: (None, 48,39,12).
You can see that this is happening because the Dense layer get input with shape (None, 48,39,8) and according to Keras implementation, Dense layer is places on top of the last dimension -> meaning: Dense layer with 128 nodes that gets input with shape (None,48,39,8) will outputs (None,48,39,**128**).

The solution depends on what you want to do and what is the shape of your labels (what the output should be).
For example, if the output shape of your model should be (nclass,1) than maybe you can Flatten the data after the MaxPool layer.
If it should be something else that change your labels shape to be (None, 48, 39, 12).

Good luck :)

Comment: thank you after put flatten after maxpool layer error goes out. but I quite do not understand what is flatten do in CNN and why it needed to add after maxpool and why it solve my problem

Comment: According to the model summary (you can print it by writing model.summary() in your code) MaxPool layer outputs **(None, 48, 39, 8)**. Flatten takes each input and reshape it to 1D array. In your case Flatten will outputs (None,48*39*8) = (None,14976). Than Dense layer will "work" on each 14976 nodes so the final output will be (None,nclass) as you wanted. Without Flatten, your Dense layer will output (None,48,39,nclass) as you can see in my answer - and that is not what you want. Hope that help you understand.. Please accept my answer and upvode if it did :)

Comment: @kimsangwon since the answer solved your issue, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents)